# Why is Replay kit not saving screen recording in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, replaykit

This code was working before but since I updated to swift 3 the screen recordings dont save anymore in my photo library when I press the save button. I also get this error message in my console when I press the save button or the cancel button.

> [Common] _BSMachError: port 5a37; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable
>   to deallocate send right"

Here is the code Im using when the screen recording is over and the previewViewController is shown:

```
internal func previewControllerDidFinish(_ previewViewController: RPPreviewViewController) {

previewViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Try this code hope it helps:

func startRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    recorder.startRecording(withMicrophoneEnabled: true) { [unowned self] (error) in
        if let unwrappedError = error {
            print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Stop", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(PreviewVC.stopRecording))
        }
    }
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

}

func stopRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

```
recorder.stopRecording { [unowned self] (preview, error) in
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Start", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(PreviewVC.startRecording))

    if let unwrappedPreview = preview {
        unwrappedPreview.previewControllerDelegate = self
        self.present(unwrappedPreview, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

}

```
func previewControllerDidFinish(_ previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```